# jQuery & zrssfeed with menu, where do I put the snippet=false and header=false

Tags: jquery

I've been using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setRSSFeed('#menu');    

    $('#menu').change(function() {
        setRSSFeed(this);
    });

    function setRSSFeed(obj) {
        var feedurl = $('option:selected', obj).val();

        if (feedurl) {
            $('#feed').rssfeed(feedurl);
        }
    }
});
```

and although I've tried (almost) everything I can't seem to be able to find where to place the following:

```
snippet=false
header=false
```

so that I can remove the header and get the pictures from the rss feeds I'm using.

The plugin I'm using is zrssfeed 1.2 which in any other configuration allows me to use both of the above settings...

It's lib is this:

(function(l){l.fn.rssfeed=function(b,h,w){h=l.extend({limit:10,offset:1,header:!0,titletag:"h4",date:!0,dateformat:"datetime",content:!0,snippet:!0,media:!0,showerror:!0,errormsg:"",key:null,ssl:!1,linktarget:"_self",linkredirect:"",linkcontent:!1,sort:"",sortasc:!0,historical:!1},h);return this.each(function(z,q){var u=l(q),f="";h.ssl&&(f="s");u.hasClass("rssFeed")||u.addClass("rssFeed");if(null==b)return!1;0'+b.title+"");m+='

  ';for(f=e.offset;fa?a="< 1 min":(3600>a?(a=Math.round(a/60)-1,c="min"):86400>a?(a=Math.round(a/3600)-1,c="hour"):604800>a?(a=Math.round(a/86400)-1,c="day"):(a=Math.round(a/604800)-1,c="week"),1'+g.title+"";e.date&&a&&(j[d].html+=""+a+"");e.content&&(g=e.snippet&&""!=g.contentSnippet?g.contentSnippet:g.content,e.linkcontent&&(g=''+g+""),j[d].html+="
  "+g+"
  ");if(e.media&&0Media files
    ';for(g=0;g'+r.split("/").pop()+" ("+s+", ",s=Math.floor(Math.log(t)/Math.log(1024)),t=(t/Math.pow(1024,Math.floor(s))).toFixed(2)+" "+"bytes kb MB GB TB PB".split(" ")[s];c.html=y+(r+t+")
    ")}j[d].html+="
  "}}e.sort&&j.sort(function(a,c){if(e.sortasc)var b=
  a.sort,d=c.sort;else b=c.sort,d=a.sort;if("date"==e.sort)return new Date(b)-new Date(d);b=b.toLowerCase();d=d.toLowerCase();return bd?1:0});l.each(j,function(a){m+=''+j[a].html+"
  ";v="odd"==v?"even":"odd"});m+="

";l(q).html(m);l("a",q).attr("target",e.linktarget)}l.isFunction(w)&&w.call(this,u)}else h.showerror&&(d=""!=h.errormsg?h.errormsg:b.responseDetails),l(q).html('

'+d+"

")})})};var p=function(b){b+="";2>b.length&&
(b="0"+b);return b},x=function(b){return"Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec".split(" ")[b]}})(jQuery);

Comment: I doubt -but am not sure -, that `rssfeed` is a default function. I assume you are using some sort of plugin? It kinda makes it tricky to debug this if we don't know what lib you are using? (please, if you have more information, don't comment it, add it to the question)

Comment: The minified library code isn't very helpful. Post a link to the plugin's documentation instead.

Comment: @Nanne You are 100% right! I edited the question to include the plugin name and js code.

Comment: @Juhana I re-edited the Q, is the code included any help to you?

Comment: Please check out the formatting a bit. Anyway, what did you try? it looks quite straightforward from the manual

Comment: Yes, the documentation is indeed very straight forward and in any other configuration I can remove the header and show the pics. In this one, I can't... can you post an example of how I should include these two params? snippet and header?

Comment: Sure, see my answer. But you said that you tried a lot: for the next question it might be usefull to add what you tried (and why it didn't work // what happend) in your question

Comment: Nanne you are a GOD! I really don't know what I've been trying or where I went wrong or why I didn't see this... but your answer delivered! Sorry to have bothered you and thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the manual, you can just add them to your call:

The manual says:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
    limit: 5
  });
});
</script>
```

So I suppose you want something like

```
 if (feedurl) {
        $('#feed').rssfeed(feedurl, {
           header: false,
           snippet: false
        });
    }
```